# IdentityServer4 and Code with PKCE testing with Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm getting started with IdentityServer4 and I made it through with resource owner flow, but since it's not recommended anymore, PKCE is, I decided to change it. I'm getting the following error message which is obvious because I'm no longer using `GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword`.

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Client not authorized for resource owner flow, check the AllowedGrantTypes setting{ client_id = trusted }, details: {
        "ClientId": "trusted",
        "ClientName": "Dayum Client",
        "GrantType": "password",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "password",
          "username": "Admin",
          "password": "***REDACTED***",
          "scope": "openid profile offline_access api1",
          "client_id": "trusted"
        }
      }
```

I don't find much information, because it's new but how am I supposed to test it with Postman? I used to do the following with resource owner flow:

```
POST http://localhost:58508/connect/token
grant_type = password
username=Admin
password=123456
scope=openid profile offline_access api1
client_id=trusted
```

I know I can't do that anymore with Code with PKCE. How do I request an access and refresh tokens, how do I test it with Postman?

Code:

```cs
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetResources() =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis() =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "trusted",
                ClientName = "Dayum Client",
                //ClientSecrets = { new Secret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".Sha256()) },

                RequireConsent = false,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,

                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:58508" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:58508" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "api1"
                },

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,  
                AccessTokenLifetime = 900,

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 1800
            }
        };
}

public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DayumConnection"],
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Configuration["Certificates:Default:Path"], Configuration["Certificates:Default:Password"]))
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DayumConnection"],
                    optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DayumConnection"],
                    optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName));

                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            })
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
            if (!context.Clients.Any())
            {
                foreach (var client in Config.GetClients())
                {
                    context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Config.GetResources())
                {
                    context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.ApiResources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Config.GetApis())
                {
                    context.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "MyArea",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is that PKCE support for OAuth 2.0 is  available in the latest version of Postman app (v7.23.0) , please update your Postman to the latest version  .

Then in `Authorization` header of Postman , set `Type` to `OAuth2`  and click the `Get New Access Token` button , set `Grant Type` to `Authorization code(With PKCE)` and set endpoints/client info as below :

[image]

And `Auth url`/`Access Token Url` is your identity server 4 's endpoints and replace the `Callback url` as your client app's redirect url  . I notice in your codes , you set the same endpoint/url host(http://localhost:58508) in identity server and client , please modify that based on your real requirements .

Comment: You make identity server app and client app in one application ? And remove `openid profile` scopes since you are using oauth2 , user is not authenticated do you config and input the correct user credential ?

Comment: the thing is that I wanted to test it without a front-end, I don't have angular built in the ASP.NET Core yet. I left only api1 in scopes as I have it in my config. I made a gif this time, because it's a bit hard to explain https://i.imgur.com/S0y2GF2.gif. Returned error: `No client identifier found` https://pastebin.com/zNrMR4mT

Comment: It seems you have got the access token .so when send token to web api cause this issue ? where is your web api and how that is protected ? Also decode the token and check what is client id in it ,

Comment: Actually, I switched to this template https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/tree/master/src because it scaffolds angular + IS4 (AddApiAuthorization way) and it also uses PKCE which is recommended to use and less code (`dotnet new angular --auth Individual`). These are my postman settings: https://i.imgur.com/bH5NYsZ.png and this is the result: https://pastebin.com/0YUE67J1 (Showing login: User is not authenticated). It redirects me to the login page. Is that normal behavior?